# Passing Sub-parsers with argparser in python

Tags: python, argparse

Basically what I am trying to achieve is this :

```
python http_client.py (get|post) [-v] (-h "k:v")* [-d inline-data] [-f file] URL
```

Now, what I did was something like this :

```
parser.add_argument('get', help='Get executes a HTTP GET request for a given URL.', default='http://httpbin.org/get')
```

But it's not working. I did some SO and these are the other links which I tried but desired output was not achieved

[Python argparse optional sub-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257403/python-argparse-optional-sub-arguments)

[How to have sub-parser arguments in separate namespace with argparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782948/how-to-have-sub-parser-arguments-in-separate-namespace-with-argparse)

Comment: Usually `argparse` questions need the full `parser` definition, not just one line.  Also show the commandline(s) that you are testing, and the resulting error(s).  Your `add_argument` so far just defines a positional with a `dest='get'`.

Comment: While `subparsers` are explained in the docs (forget that link - it's too advanced), I don't know what you mean by `sub-arguments`.  I don't see how the `sub-argument` link helps.  It's not asking for the same thing.

Comment: Watch out for that `-h`.  By default a parser already has a `-h` help definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parser produces a similar usage line:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='http_client.py')
parser.add_argument("gp", choices=['get','post'])
parser.add_argument('-v', action='version', version='0.0.1')
parser.add_argument('--how', action='append',help='k:v, may repeat')
parser.add_argument('-d', metavar='inline-data')
parser.add_argument('-f','--file')
parser.add_argument('url')

print(parser.parse_args())
```

sample help with usage.  Note that the positionals are displayed at the end, but may be interspersed with the optionals:

```
1356:~/mypy$ python stack46357414.py -h
usage: http_client.py [-h] [-v] [--how HOW] [-d inline-data] [-f FILE]
                      {get,post} url

positional arguments:
  {get,post}
  url

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v                    show program's version number and exit
  --how HOW             k:v, may repeat
  -d inline-data
  -f FILE, --file FILE
```

I assume your `-v` is supposed to be version, though `-v` is also used for a verbosity flag.

```
1357:~/mypy$ python stack46357414.py -v
0.0.1
```

example with get/post, several `how`, and required `url`

```
1357:~/mypy$ python stack46357414.py get --how 3:3 --how a:b aurl
Namespace(d=None, file=None, gp='get', how=['3:3', 'a:b'], url='aurl')
```

`argparse` does not parse `k:v` strings for you.  You get to do that after parsing.  I assume the `(-h "k:v")*` means you want to enter several of the `k:v` pairs.  `nargs='*'` is alternative to the `action='append'`.

I defined the simple `gp` positional with a choices.  That restricts the input to these 2 strings.  So far in your description I don't see a need for subparsers.

---

```
In [210]: args=argparse.Namespace(d=None, file=None, gp='get', how=['3:3', 'a:b'
     ...: ], url='aurl')
In [211]: args
Out[211]: Namespace(d=None, file=None, gp='get', how=['3:3', 'a:b'], url='aurl')
In [212]: vars(args)
Out[212]: {'d': None, 'file': None, 'gp': 'get', 'how': ['3:3', 'a:b'], 'url': 'aurl'}
In [213]: for k in args.__dict__:
     ...:     print(k, args.__dict__[k])
     ...:     
file None
d None
url aurl
gp get
how ['3:3', 'a:b']
```

Comment: somwhow I am getting trouble accessing the values of it. This is what I am trying to do  ----->>>       for k in args.__dict__:
  print (k, args.__dict__[k])